# app works if jar is local to the project and does not if it's referenced by build path (was "flexjson 3.2 strange bug")

Tags: java, eclipse, flexjson

I have two java projects in my eclipse indigo.

One of them (let's call project A) has the flexjson 3.2 jar in its lib directory.

The other project (let's call project B) has a reference to the same jar, in its build path.

Both projects connect to a REST service, get the JSON and de-serialize it using flexjson annotations.

What is weird here is that project A works and project B does not work. For project B, the deserialization just returns null silently, no exceptions thrown.

To make things better, if, instead of referencing the flexjson jar from A into B, I copy the same jar to B's lib directory and just set B build path to use the "local" jar instead of the reference, then B works.

So my doubt is: **what kind of problem this jar may have or what kind of problem eclipse indigo may have in this case**?

ps. no I am not using maven.

Answer (score 1):

Close project A and then try.This could be happening because of the jar being used by multiple threads.

Comment: tried that. no threads involved. but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Are your projects residing in different drives? If yes, have you checked the file permissions of the project location

Comment: Are both projects having same named java objects which are getting deserialized?